# Incompatibility Issue Between Firebase and Flutter Libraries

Tags: java, flutter, kotlin, mobile

I am working on an old project and these are the errors I encountered, but I couldn't find a solution. How can I fix this

**ERROR:**

```
/C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging_web-2.4.4/lib/src/internals.dart:2:1: Error: Error when reading '/C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/src/internals.dart': Sistem belirtilen dosyayı bulamıyor.

export 'package:firebase_core/src/internals.dart' hide guardWebExceptions;
^
/C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging_web-2.4.4/lib/src/internals.dart:6:8: Error: Error when reading '/C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/src/internals.dart': Sistem belirtilen dosyayı bulamıyor.

import 'package:firebase_core/src/internals.dart' as internals;
       ^
/C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/src/firebase_app.dart:18:25: Error: Member not found: 'FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends'.
    FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends(_delegate);
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging_web-2.4.4/lib/src/internals.dart:11:20: Error: Method not found: 'guardWebExceptions'.
  return internals.guardWebExceptions(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/photo_view-0.11.1/lib/src/core/photo_view_gesture_detector.dart:106:29: Error: The argument type 'PointerEvent' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PointerDownEvent'.
 - 'PointerEvent' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/events.dart' ('/C:/Src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/events.dart').
 - 'PointerDownEvent' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/events.dart' ('/C:/Src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/events.dart').
    super.addAllowedPointer(event);
```

**dependencies:**

```
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.5
  firebase_auth: ^2.0.0
  in_app_purchase: ^0.6.0+1
  uuid: ^3.0.4
  firebase_storage: ^10.2.8
  cloud_firestore: ^3.1.9
  firebase_core: ^1.11.0
  permission_handler: ^7.1.0
  image_picker: ^0.7.4
  agora_rtc_engine: ^4.0.0-rc.3
  audioplayers: ^0.19.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^5.0.0+4
  firebase_messaging: ^10.0.3
  connectycube_flutter_call_kit: ^0.1.0-dev.1
  flutter_email_sender: ^5.0.0
  all_sensors: ^0.3.1+2
  url_launcher: ^6.0.3
  photo_view: ^0.11.1
  carousel_slider: ^4.0.0-nullsafety.0
  google_nav_bar: ^5.0.3
  expansion_card: ^0.1.0
  google_fonts: ^2.0.0
  get: ^4.1.4
```

I tried upgrading the versions, it didn't work, my goal is to get the project running

Comment: Can you please provide me a your Flutter version?